# How to remove all "xts" "zoo" object from R environment?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I need help on removing all "xts" "zoo" object from R (global)environment.

I learned that I can remove dataframes by using the following:

`rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "data.frame"])`

The object I am trying to remove from environment is called `temp`. Running the following:
`class(temp)` yields `[1] "xts" "zoo"`.

So I modified the code for deleting data frames like so:
`rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "xts"])`
or
`rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "zoo"])`
and other combinations of the "xts" and/or "zoo" but none of them works.

The temp object was created using `temp <- as.xts(as.data.table(data))`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to compare it to the class() output of a dummy xts object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may try

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), \(x) class(x)[[1]]) == "xts"])
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Filter`:

```
rm(list = Filter(function(x) 'xts' %in% class(get(x)), ls(all = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you. your code works too.